# Adding index list and section headers to translated tableview

Tags: swift, tableview

How to add section headers and index list to `UITableView` in **this use case**?

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var detail: Detail? = nil
var list = [tabledata]()
let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    list = [

        tabledata(name:"something".localized, sort:"sort.something".localized, id:"something.html"),
        tabledata(name:"somethingelse".localized, sort:"sort.somethingelse".localized, id:"somethingelse.html"),
        ...

    ]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "library", for: indexPath)
    var data: tabledata
    data = list[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = data.name
    return cell

}
```

**Now the point is that table data are going to be translated.**

> Like if the user has set the language to English, sorting is unneeded;
> but if the language is set to German etc., section headers have to be applied to translated table.

**Can someone figure out how to call a section letter from inside the dictionary, like**

```
tabledata(section: "a", name:"anaconda".localized, sort:"sort.anaconda".localized, id:"anaconda.html")
```

Note that

- `name:` is the actual cell name going to be **`.localized`**
- `sort:` has to help characters like `á` `é` etc. in cell name to sort properly (avoiding them to show in the end of alphabet)
- `id:` calls the html file location to display in `detailViewController` ('cause name has to be translated and we want a static text here)

**A usual implementation of section headers and index list** will result in something like

```
T                 // section header
translation       // cell names
transmission
...

T                 // table in
Übersetzung       // another language
Getriebe
...
```

> Maybe there could be a **`function()`** which will get all the `section`s from `tabledata` and assign them to corresponding letters in `var sectionletters = ["A", "B", ...]` but that's above my beginner-limited knowledge.

### **What's the correct model for translated tableview?**

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried implementing the tableview delegate function `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` and providing a header view for each section?

Comment: how exactly can I do that? can you make this an answer?

Comment: I added an answer with the approach I'd use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. One of the simplest is to use the delegate functions provided with UITableView.

For organizational purposes I'd start by creating a class to represent sections. Something like this:

```
class GhostSection {

    // a title for this section
    var sectionTitle: String

    // a list of items for this particular section
    var items: [Ghost] = []

    init(title: String, items: [Ghost]) {
        sectionTitle = title
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

Then update the `list` variable to use the sections instead of a raw list of items:

```
var tabledata = [GhostSections]()
```

Ideally I'd create my GhostSection from a json object, but if it must be done manually then something like this would work:

```
// setup the table data to use GhostSection instances for each section
var tabledata = [
    GhostSection(title: "a", items: [Ghost(name:"an".localized, sort:"sort.an".localized, id:"0101")]),
    GhostSection(title: "b", items: [Ghost(name:"bc".localized, sort:"sort.bc".localized, id:"0102")]),
    GhostSection(title: "c", items: [Ghost(name:"cd".localized, sort:"sort.cd".localized, id:"0103")])
]
```

I'd have `numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView)` return the tabledata count, which would be the count of the total number of sections:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tabledata.count
}
```

and the `numberOfRowsInSection` return the list count for each `items` array on each `GhostSection` in your tabledata array:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tabledata[section].items.count
}
```

Then I'd update `cellForRow(at indexPath)` to return the info for the right cell in that section:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "library", for: indexPath)
    // this gets the section data, then gets the item from that section
    var data = list[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = data.name
    return cell

}
```

I also like to create my headers as reusable nib views, so the ListHeaderView just has a title label in it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    // this loads the view from the nib
    guard let view = ListHeaderView.fromNib() as? ListHeaderView else {
        return nil
    }

    // get the section object for this current section
    let data = tabledata[section]

    // and set the title label text here from our section object
    view.titleLabel.text = data.sectionTitle
    return view
}

// if you want to also have a custom footer you can do that here...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView()
}

// and let the header height be dynamic, or return a set height here...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

In case you want to use this approach here's how I implemented the `fromNib()` function so you can instantiate any view that has an associated .xib file:

```
public extension UIView {

    public static func fromNib() -> UIView? {
        let nibName = String(describing: self)
        let bundle = Bundle(for: self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? UIView else {
            print("Unable to instantiate nib named: \(nibName) in bundle: \(String(describing: bundle)) -- nib: \(String(describing: nib))")
            return nil
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Also note it's a good idea to get in the habit of using camel case for class/object names with the first letter capitalized IF you want to keep with current conventions. So instead of naming your class `ghost` get in the habit of doing `Ghost`. For variables the convention is also camel case but start with a lowercase.

Comment: Thanks! So I have to create a class for each particular section, right? Like class SectionA then var sectionTitle = "a"?

Comment: No, you do not create a class for each section. You create an instance of `GhostSection` for each section. Huge difference.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @rmaddy, I missed that detail. ;)

Comment: Okay but now how to create an instance of GhostSection for each section and how to change the list variable to handle sections?

Comment: I've updated with more detail creating the table data with instances of GhostSection, in my examples I've changed the name of your `list` variable to `tabledata`, and setting it up the way I did it is already handling the sections. I'd also suggest finding some good tutorials on using UITableViews to round out your knowledge of how they're used and what you can do with them. raywenderlich.com has some good tutorials I've used.

Comment: that tutorials are good but I was unlucky to find one for this kind of dictionary... sorry if I am too unprofessional, the only thing I still can't understand well is where to put class GhostSection; wherever I put it, tells it has no initializers and "keyword 'init' (in that class) cannot be used as an identifier here"

Comment: @TomášPánik no problem, this site is for learning, I’ve learned a lot from it as well over the years. I wrote that class in the answer field without validation so I probably missed something, I’ll check and update it a little later when I’m back at my computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177374/discussion-between-digitalhound-and-tomas-panik).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use sections: one section for each first letter.

First, update your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` to deal with sections: the first word in a section corresponds to the row value 0.
The section number corresponds to the letter: 0 for A, 1 for B, ...

In your code, you get an old cell correctly, but the way you set the text must be changed. You are doing something like that: `cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]`. But this will not work because with sections, the `indexPath.row` parameter value is no longer the index of the ghost in your list: your list is a 1-dimension array, but with sections, UIKit uses a two dimensional way to give you the reference to the ghost: the arguments `indexPath.row` is now the index number of the ghost in the section `indexPath.section`. So if you have 4 ghost names, in your list, for instance "axx" (section 0, row 0), "ayy" (section 0, row 1), "bxx" (section 1, row 0) and "byy" (section 1, row 1), the values of the arguments to refer to "bxx", for instance, are 1 for `indexPath.section` and 0 for `indexPath.row`. With your current line of code, you will set the following text: list[0], so "axx". But it's "bxx" that corresponds to section 1 and row 0.

To get the correct behavior, you may process the whole list of ghosts, extract the ones that correspond to the letter for `indexPath.section` into another array, and finally get the element of this new array that has an index that equals to `indexPath.row`.

**But as you see, this is a bit more tricky than we would like.
The best way to do all of that, easily, is to change your data source type**: use a 2-dimensional array instead of your list that is of type `[ghost]`.
You could for instance use something like:

```
var myNewDataSource : [String: [ghost]] = [
    "A": [ghost1withNameStartingWithA, ghost2withNameStartingWithA, ...],
    "B": [ghost1withNameStartingWithB, ghost2withNameStartingWithB, ...],
...
]
```

This way, everything is simpler.

Now, override this function, to have 26 letters or sections (you may customize this function if you want to display only letters containing at least one word):

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 26
}
```

Override and implement correctly this function, to indicate how many words there are in a section, in your dictionary:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    [ COMPUTE THE NUMBER OF ROWS/WORDS FOR THIS LETTER AND RETURN THE VALUE ]
}
```

Then return a String with the letter for each section, in order to display this letter in the GUI:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    [ RETURN THE LETTER CORRESPONDING TO THE SECTION: "A" for section 0, "B" for section 1, etc. ]
}
```

Finally, customize your sections, since you seems to want a specific background color and maybe a bold font or another font size, according to your screenshot:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 253.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 196.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    header.textLabel?.textColor = .black
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 19)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please be more specific, what you mean by updating cellForRowAt to deal with sections?

Comment: *"The easiest way is to use sections"* - that's the only way to do it right.

Comment: Yes I understand it but I need also name: sort: and id: to handle translation properly while loading the table... can I make somehow a dictionary like list was and put there section letters?

Comment: Yes, you can do many things like that, the only important constraint is that you must be able to access your word easily with the index of the first letter and the index of the word in the list of those words that share this first later. You may have redundancy, for easily accessing things or reordering simply. The type must help you maintain your data for the processes you need to implement, and simultaneously to be able to access a word easily when only knowing the row and section indexes. Any type that complies to both of these needs is perfect.